# Aligning hundreds of rasters quickly?

Tags: arcpy, raster, georeferencing, imagery, alignment

I'm hoping to accurately align hundreds of aerial images that are slightly off-kilter.  The images cover the same area on different dates (several acres).  They contain identifiable features around the edge (roads) but vegetation in the middle.

Is there any way to do this?

I know ArcGIS has the automatic georeference toolbar - which I've used with limited success.

Anything else out there?

Comment: Why are they slightly off? Are they unrectified images (raw photos) that need to be orthorectified?

Comment: They are orthorectified roughly - the georefencing process was done inaccurately by someone else.  So now I'd ideally like to align them in some automatic way, via command-line perhaps.

Comment: In this case I don't know of anything that will auto-correlate your images without parameters, time to roll up the sleeves and use the georeference toolbar, possibly with a 3rd order polynomial to try to correct bad orthorectification.

Comment: Its not clear whether you have tried the automatic georeferencing of rasters that is now available in ArcGIS Desktop: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/georeferencing-a-raster-automatically.htm

Comment: @PolyGeo hi there, I actually reference that in the post: "I know ArcGIS has the automatic georeference toolbar - which I've used with limited success."  I found that it wasn't all that accurate in it's georeferencing for my situation.

Comment: I'm not sure if I saw that at the time I commented but, in any event, I think you should provide more details about your situation, and how you tested it before concluding that it was unsuitable.